# Systemd service dependent on Generated init.d service

Tags: networking, systemd

The system I'm on uses systemd, but the network bringup is still on old init.d scripts. I've added an systemd service to run on system boot, but I want to make sure it is run before the network setup occurs. Where can I specify this behaviour and how?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the name of your legacy init.d script which sets up the network. Systemd has a service for it. Then you need to add Before= directive to your service. Ex, if there is something like /etc/rc5.d/network systemd will have a service network.service. Then just add Before=network.service.